# Swipe Gestures on 23.04 wayland

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I just installed ubuntu 23.04 a week ago and actually using gestures on ubuntu made me crazy
1- swipe 2 fingers left and right to go back and forward of browsers dosnt work and also
2- I can't zoom in applications with 2 fingers also
3- I would like to custom function of 4 finger to volume up and down and it's way difficult I can't understand how to solve it and
4-  i would like to Increase touchpad Sensitivity more than the max of ubuntu settings

I was doing this settings on Windows but How could I do that on ubuntu?